# Car broke down within 30 days of purchase. Recourse?

Tags: business

I live in Omaha Nebraska. I financed a car (2001 Mercury Sable) through a "buy here pay here" lot located in Council Bluffs Iowa. The car was sold "as is, no warrenty". The car was acquired less than 30 days ago.

Exactly 16 days after purchase, the car will not start. I believe the starter is bad.

Is there any recourse I can pursue? The Iowa lemon law does not seem to cover previously titled vehicles. Are there any other regulations that would allow me to receive some compensation or perhaps a replacement part or vehicle?

Comment: Looks like you're out of luck, unless you go back to the car lot and complain; they might help out of good faith for a customer.

Comment: This is why you should never buy an as-is vehicle for use as transportation.

Comment: @barbecue "As is" is par for the course at used car lots. Some people don't have a economic choice. But some states have better consumer protection laws than others.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Understood, but it's not safe to assume that an as-is vehicle is reliable transportation. Being sold as-is means the dealer doesn't think it's worth the risk of offering a warranty.

Comment: Those are either personal or third-party business choices that have little or nothing to do with the law.

Answer (score 4):

An as is, no warranty sale means [you have no legal recourse](https://dmv.nebraska.gov/legal/lemon-law#asis) against the dealer.

Comment: True, provided there is no proof of intentional fraud on the part of the seller, which might have supported a motion for voiding the entire contract and its disclaimers.

Comment: @Upnorth what would constitute "intentional fraud"?

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Under Nebraska statutes, it seems to be called "theft by deception": "A person commits theft if he obtains property of another by deception. A person deceives if he intentionally: (1) Creates or reinforces a false impression, including false impressions as to law, value, intention, or other state of mind;..."  NRS 28-512. In theory, if you have proof that the seller lied about something you asked, or prevented you from knowing something important to the deal, those could be evidence of "fraud". Your AG's office has a consume protection division, where you may file a complaint.

Comment: @konnerrasmussen There is also "civil fraud", about which you may read on many Nebraska lawyers' websites and their affiliates, perhaps by searching "nebraska fraud tort".  Good luck.